# How to change my EC2 instance listen to new folder

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I have a running EC2 instance in Linux (Apache server). I recently cloned another repository to my EC2 instance.
For example :
In **var/wwww/html** there are two folders

1. **front**(already running)
2. **frontend**(newly cloned)

I wanted the instance to listen, folder **frontend**

Methods tried :

1. changed root directory in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** to

> ```
>  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
> ```

```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/frontend/dist
   <Directory "/var/www/html/frontend/dist">
      FallbackResource /index.html
   </Directory>
```

and restarted Apache

2. Tried stopping the instance and started again
3. tried rewrite mode by `sudo a2enmod rewrite` - shows rewrite mode already enabled

Comment: Did you also make changes in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file?

Comment: In `apache2.conf` there is `allow override` for `/var/www/html` it is changed from `none` to `All` . nothing related to document root is there

Comment: I think You need to change `/var/www/html` to your preferred directory as you have changed in `000-default.conf`.

Comment: I found the issue why the root directory change is not reflecting. I installed SSL for my domain ,so i have to change root file inside SSL conf file also ( in `000-default-ssl.conf` ). Thank you @ArpitJain really appreciate your efforts.